# Set visible state for values in recyclerview when its empty

Tags: android

If list is empty I would like show another view. I thought everything should work, do you have any idea why it doesn't display?
Even if I set in layout for:

> vErrorStateNotification for -> android:visibility="visible"

I can't see anything.

layout

```
<com.base.ui.view.FullScreenErrorStateView
    android:id="@+id/vErrorStateNotification"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

fragment

```
private fun collectNotificationItems() {
    vm.notificationData.collectWith(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        if (it.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d("it", "isEmpty")
            layout.rvNotificationItems.visibility = View.GONE
            layout.tvNotificationTitle.visibility = View.GONE
            layout.vErrorStateNotification.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            collectErrorState()
            vm.setEmptyStateVisible(true)
            notificationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        } else {
            Log.d("it", "isEmptyElse")
            layout.vErrorStateNotification.visibility = View.GONE
            layout.tvNotificationTitle.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            layout.rvNotificationItems.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            notificationAdapter.items = it
            notificationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

viewmodel

```
private val _errorStateUIModel = MutableStateFlow<ErrorStateUIModel>(NotificationEmptyState())
val errorStateUIModel = _errorStateUIModel.asSharedFlow()
private val _isErrorStateVisible = MutableStateFlow(false)
val isErrorStateVisible = _isErrorStateVisible.asStateFlow()
```

[..]

```
fun setEmptyStateVisible(isVisible: Boolean) = viewModelScope.launch {
    _isErrorStateVisible.value = isVisible
    if (isVisible) {
        _errorStateUIModel.emit(NotificationEmptyState())
    }
}
```

emptystate class

```
class NotificationEmptyState : ErrorStateUIModel(
    title = R.string.list_title_empty_state,
    description = R.string.list_description_empty_state,
    icon = R.drawable.imempty_state
)
```

Where could be an issue in that case?

EDIT:
Screens from debugger
[image]
[image]

[image]

EDIT2:
IT WORKS

Wrong place in .xml file...
It should be under linearlayout not under SwipeToRefersh*

Comment: Try debugging ...

Comment: Ok I have done it looks like everything is fine. The state is loaded and overwritten data.
Screen in EDIT post.
But there are some error I do not understand and _isErrorStateVisisble is on false

Comment: ok I make edit it works... :) Wrong place in .xml file

Comment: hmmm but now I have another issue: My swiperefresh works only under the errorstateview not from the highest place in height..

Comment: Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70201067/how-to-fix-swiperefresh-when-one-view-is-visible-invisible