# How to fix swiperefresh when one view is visible/invisible

Tags: android

I have recyclerview list.
If list is empty recyclerview goes to invisible or gone and another view appears to visible
If list is not empty recyclerview goes to visible.

It works fine, but when we have empty list another view appears I can't swipe to refresh in the right place (look at the screen).

I tried https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy/issues/74 but it hadn't help me.

my xml

```
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.example.deepdiveandroid.base.ui.view.FullScreenErrorStateView
            android:id="@+id/vErrorStateNotification"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/vSwipeToRefreshNotification"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvNotificationItems"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_16"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_72"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:listitem="@layout/layout_list_item_notification" />
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your xml layout to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.example.deepdiveandroid.base.ui.view.FullScreenErrorStateView
            android:id="@+id/vErrorStateNotification"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvNotificationItems"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_16"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_72"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/layout_list_item_notification" />

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```